# turn json obj to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array of objects

```
[{
    "A": "thisA",
    "B": "thisB",
    "C": "thisC"
}, {
    "A": "thatA",
    "B": "thatB",
    "C": "thatC"
}]
```

I'm trying to get this format as an end result: `[["thisA","thisC"], ["thatA","thatC"]]`

I'm trying with a for loop

```
var arr = [],
    arr2 = [];
for (var = i; i < obj.length; i++) {
    arr.push(obj[i].A, obj[i].C);
    arr2.push(arr);
}
```

but I end up having `["thisA","thisC","thatA","thatC"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `map()` method.

```js
const data = [{"A": "thisA","B": "thisB","C": "thisC"}, {"A": "thatA","B": "thatB","C": "thatC"}]

const result = data.map(({A, C}) => [A, C]);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: clean and simple

Answer (score 2):

You coulöd push an array with the values. Beside that, you need to initialize `i` with zero.

```js
var objects = [{ A: "thisA", B: "thisB", C: "thisC" }, { A: "thatA", B: "thatB", C: "thatC" }],
    array = [],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    array.push([objects[i].A, objects[i].C]);
}

console.log(array);
```